# Count columns satisfying a multiple OR statement and an AND statement

Tags: r

I would like to count the number of columns, in each row of a data frame, that satisfy a multiple OR condition.

In the first 100 columns of my data frame I have "codes" (that are integers). Let's say I want the number of columns where the value is either 111,112 or 113.

I tried

```
rowSums(mydata[,1:100]==111 | mydata[,1:100] == 112 | mydata[,1:100] == 113)
```

This works, but as I have a lot of codes to check I would prefer to use an %in% statement like

```
rowSums(mydata[,1:100] %in% c(111,112,113))
```

but this does not work and I haven't been able to find the appropriate syntax. (I looked at other questions about %in% but I didn't find any answer that solved my problem.)

The second part of the question is, how to add an AND condition on other columns ? Something like

```
rowSums(mydata[,1:100] %in% c(111,112,113) & mydata[,101:200] %in% c("a","b","c"))
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `%in%` operator doesn't work with `data.frame`.  We could loop through the columns using `lapply/sapply/vapply` and do the `%in%`.  After we are get the logical index in a `list`, we get the elementwise sum (`+`) using `Reduce`.  This would also work even if there are `NA` values as `%in%` uses `match` with argument `nomatch=0L` while `==` returns `NA` for `NA` values.

```
 Reduce(`+`, lapply(mydata[1:5], `%in%` ,111:113))
 #[1] 2 3 2 4 2 1 3 0 1 2 1 2 1 2 0 1 1 3 2 2
```

which is equal to `rowSums`

```
rowSums(mydata[1:5] ==111 | mydata[1:5] == 112 | mydata[1:5] == 113)
#[1] 2 3 2 4 2 1 3 0 1 2 1 2 1 2 0 1 1 3 2 2
```

---

For the second part of the question, we can construct the `&` with `Map` and then use `Reduce` to get the `+`.

We use two logical `list`s (`lapply(mydata[1:5], ...)` and `lapply(mydata[6:10], ...)`) as input for `Map`.  The `&` will compare the corresponding `list` elements and return `TRUE` if both are `TRUE` or else `FALSE` to return a single `list`.  From there, we can use `Reduce` as stated before.

```
 Reduce(`+`, Map(`&`, lapply(mydata[1:5], `%in%` ,111:113), 
              lapply(mydata[6:10], `%in%`, letters[1:3])))
 #[1] 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 2 1 0
```

The equivalent `rowSums` code would be

```
rowSums((mydata[1:5] ==111 | mydata[1:5] == 112 | mydata[1:5] == 113) & 
         (mydata[6:10]=='a' | mydata[6:10]=='b' | mydata[6:10]=='c'))
#[1] 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 2 1 0
```

NOTE: Here I created a small example dataset of 10 columns.  The first 5 are 'numeric', followed by 5 'character' columns.

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
mydata <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(111:120, 5*20, replace=TRUE), 
        ncol=5))
set.seed(42)
mydata2 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(letters[1:10], 5*20, 
        replace=TRUE), ncol=5), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

mydata <- cbind(mydata, mydata2)
```

Comment: @VeerendraGadekar Thanks.  You could use `setDT(mydata)[, Reduce('+', lapply(.SD, '%in%', 111:113)), .SDcols=1:5]`

Comment: Thank you, I had never heard of the functions Reduce and Map ! Very informative answer. What was Veerendra Gadekar's question? It is not visible anymore

Comment: @Astarte Thanks for the feedback.  VeerendraGadekar would like to do the same thing using `data.table`.